# cx-Freeze Executable Won't Run on Another Computer

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit, cx-freeze

I wrote a program in Python and created an executable with cx-Freeze. I had to include tk and tcl libraries, as well as some images, in the setup.py for the executable to run correctly.

I linked these files to absolute paths on my computer, thinking that cx-freeze would copy these files over to the final executable folder so that it would become a part of its own package.

The program runs perfectly on my PC, but does not run on my colleague's PC.

Including the tcl and tk libraries as well as the images was a part of my troubleshooting process when the .exe wouldn't run. I have no idea of what to do next.

```
'''This is my setup.py file.'''

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
import os

includes = []

include_files = 
 [r"C:\Users\jchoujaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\tcl86t.dll",
                 r"C:\Users\jchoujaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\tk86t.dll",
                 r"C:\Users\jchoujaa\Desktop\Code\STARx App\Savvy Logger\Developer\Imaging\savron.png",
         r"C:\Users\jchoujaa\Desktop\Code\STARx App\Savvy Logger\Developer\Imaging\s-icon.ico",
         r"C:\Users\jchoujaa\Desktop\Code\STARx App\Savvy Logger\Developer\Imaging\STAR.png"]

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\jchoujaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\jchoujaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\tcl\tk8.6'

base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform == 'win32' else None

setup(name = "SavvyLogger",
        version = "1.0",
        description = "Logger Interpreter",
        options={"build_exe": {"includes": includes, "include_files": include_files, 'packages': ['pandas', 'numpy']}},
        executables = [Executable("SavvyLogger.py", base=base)])
```

This is the error my colleague receives when attempting to open my executable:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCeON.png)

Comment: The error did mention `s-icon.ico` is not defined. Did you double check with your colleague that the file was indeed included? And also did you hard code the path to the `ico` file in your code, instead of relative path?

Comment: s-icon.ico was included in the folder that I sent him. But yes, it was hard coded: pre.wm_iconbitmap = (desktop + "Code\\STARx App\\Savvy Logger\\Developer\\Imaging\\s-icon.ico")
How would I create a relative path for this?

Comment: If you look carefully at the error again - there is a discrepancy on the path. The defined path links to `C:\Users\bboulay...`, but error was raised from `C:\Users\jchoujaa...`.

Comment: If you put the `ico` file in the same location as your initial py file, you can just put `pre.wm_iconbitmap =  "s-icon.ico"`.

Comment: I'm going to try that, thanks Henry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Henry Yik's suggestion in the comments worked.

The problem was that I had set the path of the images used by tkinter to a folder located on my desktop.

Henry suggested I place the image files in the same folder as my .py script and remove the path names from the image variables.

This worked!